# Why does dojo require firebug after a dojo build?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo-build

I am trying to figure out why, after building a dojo application into a single layer does dojo still include the extra file for `dojo/_firebug/firebug`?

It does not download the file in Chrome on Windows 7 on a desktop PC, however, it does download it on Chrome on a Windows 8 tablet.

The reason this is a problem, is because I have a grunt task that runs after the dojo build to remove all extra .js files (all javascript files are being built into a layer).

Comment: Its there incase you turn the debug:true flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops, I figured this out thanks to @tik27. The `debug:true` flag was set in my `dojoConfig` so it was downloading this extra file.

Cheers.